# Is it possible to read raw bit of recevied inside MCP2515 RX?

Tags: can

We are using [MAX33015E](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/MAX33011E-MAX33015E.pdf) with MCP2515 CAN controller. The MAX33011E has internal fault detection which should be good thing. Our issue that when MAX33011E detects a fault it `shutdown` the bus and sending the `fault code` over `RX` into the MCP2515. The fault code is 6 bit long and it is not standard CANFRAME.

Is it possible to read the "raw" bits the MCP2515 receives even that it is not a legal CANFRAME?

## EDIT 1

few remark:
This is a basic CANBUS design
[image: general canbus design]

The MAX33015E is unsual in the sense it reports an error to the `CAN controller` via TXD without legal CANFRAME

We run Linux, we can patch the MCP2515 driver if needed. But how can we force it to transmit when the Transceiver is dead?

[image: MAX33015E fault reporting]

The way to `clear` the fault state, i.e to restore the Transceiver to work is to transmit 10 cycles, can be a valid canframe that the controller transmit.

[image: MAX33015E fault clear]

Our issue: when the `MAX33015E transceiver` in a "fault state". We did not succeed to  transmit with the `mcp2515 Controller`

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I only took a glance at the datasheet but it would appear that faults are reported over the FAULT pin, not anywhere else. Traditionally, CAN transceivers are very "dumb" and only translate signals and voltage levels - they don't mess around with the data.

> The fault code is 6 bit long and it is not standard CANFRAME.

This sounds very much like a standard CAN error frame produced by the CAN controller and not by the transceiver. You can easily see where it comes from by monitoring the CAN Tx and Rx signals of the controller with a scope. The error frame is present on the Tx line from your controller, most likely. In which case it was generated by the controller as expected.

Here is a good tutorial about CAN error frames: [CAN Bus Errors Explained - A Simple Intro](https://www.csselectronics.com/pages/can-bus-errors-intro-tutorial) (I'm not affiliated). As for what could be causing error frames, see this beginner FAQ: [What are the most common causes of CAN bus communication errors?](https://electrical.codidact.com/posts/276251)

Perhaps this is simply the #1 all time most common beginner FAQ: is there another CAN node present or not?

Comment: thanks for the quick answer, I have updated my question with more details, as the main issue, the Fault reports on the RX line and killed it, therefore the MCP2515 cannot recover and does not allow to send any data, at least we did not succeed to do so